# Firestore: Show Collection Documents in Console

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, console.log

I have a flutter app that using firestore database and I want to show data from "products" collection in the console but what I receive is this:

```
I/flutter ( 5747): Instance of 'Future<QuerySnapshot>'
```

Is there a way to achieve it .. here is my code:

```
Future<void> getItems() async {
  final response = await Firestore.instance.collection("products").getDocuments();
  print(json.decode(json.decode(response)));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
  Future<void> getItems() async {
  final response = await Firestore.instance.collection("products").getDocuments();
  response.documents.forEach((element) {
    print(element.data);
  });
}
```

Since you are using `await`, then `getDocuments()` should return a `QuerySnapshot`, and then you can use `documents` and iterate.

Comment: I tried it but It gives me  Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'

Comment: `print(element.data);`